# Visual Studio 2013 installation doesn't process after displaying logo

Tags: visual-studio-2013, installation

I'm trying to install visual studio 2013. I have an iso file and I'm mounting image to drive but the installation doesn't process anything after displaying Visual Studio logo and a black rectangle after that.

[Visual Studio logo appears. See Image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6O_VsvFdVvpQmRfM3RMenpfa3M/edit?usp=sharing)

Now logo gets disappear and there is a black rectangle box in front of me.
[See Image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6O_VsvFdVvpa0E3UTBCT2txc00/edit?usp=sharing)

I can move the box by pressing mouse button and moving it even with 2 inch below the box.

I have Windows7 32 bit with service pack 1 installed in my desktop. Core i3 and Intel HD graphics. I have Titanium Studio, Visual Studio 2010 and other regular softwares installed as well.

The exactly same issue happens when I attempt to install VS2012.

Comment: Check with MS support center.

Comment: Exactly the same problem. And no useful information on stackoverflow :(

Answer (score 0):

I googled quite a while and found some topics on https://social.msdn.microsoft.com complaining this issue. Basically, the answers ask to check Windows Update and make sure it's up-to-date, especially .NET framework to version 4.5.x. So I do this, and after installing updates and restarting several times, it finally works. Maybe you can try this way too.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution for myself. I was using a software which was protecting my pc's graphic driver and was using another one. I removed that and VS installed as usually.

You should try to install at least once without any driver in your system if you are facing such issue.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was a missing file machine.config in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\CONFIG. I copied the file from another PC and installation of VS2013 immediately started, and completed successfully.